# Xamarin Studio - can not login - One of the identified items was in an invalid format

Tags: xamarin

As part of my Microsoft Action Visual Studio eligibility for using/developing in Xamarin I'm trying to login in Xamarin Studio (Mac). I still have Xamarin Studio on my Mac (until recently I had an Indie subscription). Now when trying to login I get the error message(s) below.

Anyone an idea how to avoid this error?

Thanks.

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) [0x00264] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:762 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService+<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x00410] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:654 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationWorkflowStep step) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:463 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog+<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0005b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/8dc6bca6/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:561
```

Answer (score 6):

Guys from Xamarin Support already post an answer to this
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63675/activation-error/p1

In general you should

Update to the "Cycle 6 – Service Release 3" versions or newer.
The minimum version of Xamarin Studio that supports MSDN licenses is here: http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Mac/XamarinStudio-5.10.3.51-0.dmg

Log out and log back into your Xamarin account following the "Quick manual refresh steps" on https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1641743-how-do-i-manually-resynchronize-xamarin-licenses-.

Answer (score 1):

Update Xamarin to the latest stable version. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in grid I had added ** instead of *,
ie:

```
<RowDefinition Height="**" />
```

instead of

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

Check if same applies to you