# Error Logging Into Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio with Xamarin Enterprise Account

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am having trouble logging back into my Visual Studio Xamarin Account after Xamarin automatically signed me out. I am receiving the following error message:

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid
format. at
Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) at
Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.d__61.MoveNext() at
Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep step) at
Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.b__0(Task t)
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Check this bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17613 and the workarounds listed there. There are also solutions in this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462016/xamarin-activation-fails-in-my-visual-studio-2015-enterprise/36462744#36462744

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Studio - can not login - One of the identified items was in an invalid format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350987/xamarin-studio-can-not-login-one-of-the-identified-items-was-in-an-invalid-f)